# Issue executing stored procedure that has dynamic columns from script which uses dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I have created a stored procedure which takes a list of dynamic columns (based on selected parameters) and then concatenates them. This is then saved to a global temp table and then passed into a dynamic SQL statement which will pass the column names as per the parameters. When I run another script which executes this stored procedure it complains saying:

---

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC (@SqlCommand)' 
>   in procedure 'CL_GetDynamicColumns2'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using    the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.

The problem here is that I cannot use WITH RESULT SETS because the output of the columns are dynamic and I never know how many columns will be returned. The column names are always outputted differently (if the parameters are changed).

Is it possible to create a function perhaps that will dynamically get the columns I want instead of using dynamic SQL?

```
--Script 1: Everything is first generated in this stored proc
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CL_GetDynamicColumns2]
(
@TableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Currency NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Type NVARCHAR(MAX),
@ParameterValue NVARCHAR(MAX),
@WhereField NVARCHAR(MAX),
@ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE
(  
[TABLE_CATALOG] nvarchar(128),
[TABLE_SCHEMA] nvarchar(128),
[TABLE_NAME] nvarchar(128),
[COLUMN_NAME] nvarchar(128),
[ORDINAL_POSITION] INT,
[COLUMN_DEFAULT] NVARCHAR(4000),
[IS_NULLABLE] VARCHAR(3),
[DATA_TYPE] nvarchar(128),
[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] INT,
[CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH] INT,
[NUMERIC_PRECISION] TINYINT,
[NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX] SMALLINT,
[NUMERIC_SCALE] INT,
[DATETIME_PRECISION] SMALLINT,
[CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG] nvarchar(128),
[CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA] nvarchar(128),
[CHARACTER_SET_NAME] nvarchar(128),
[COLLATION_CATALOG] nvarchar(128),
[COLLATION_SCHEMA] nvarchar(128),
[COLLATION_NAME] nvarchar(128),
[DOMAIN_CATALOG] nvarchar(128),
[DOMAIN_SCHEMA] nvarchar(128),
[DOMAIN_NAME] nvarchar(128)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns AS C
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
AND C.DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('decimal','numeric')

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns AS C
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
AND C.DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal','numeric')
AND C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%' + @Currency + '%'
AND C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%' + @Type + '%'


DECLARE @MyTableVar2 TABLE
(  
[TABLE_CATALOG] nvarchar(128),
[TABLE_SCHEMA] nvarchar(128),
[TABLE_NAME] nvarchar(128),
[TABLE_COLUMNS] nvarchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar2 ([TABLE_CATALOG], [TABLE_SCHEMA], [TABLE_NAME], 
[TABLE_COLUMNS])

SELECT DISTINCT T.TABLE_CATALOG, T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME, 
STUFF(
      (SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
      FROM @MyTableVar AS TC
      WHERE TC.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS TABLE_COLUMNS
 FROM @MyTableVar AS T

 /*Final step: Build Dynamic Query*/

 SET @ColumnList = (SELECT L.TABLE_COLUMNS FROM @MyTableVar2 AS L)

 SET @SqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnList + 
            ' Into ##TempCatch ' + 
            ' FROM ' + @TableName + 
             ' WHERE ' + @WhereField + ' IN ' + '(SELECT * FROM ' + 
 'dbo.fnToDelimitedTable( ' + @ParameterValue + ' ,'',''))'

 EXEC (@SqlCommand)

 SELECT * FROM ##TempCatch
 DROP TABLE ##TempCatch

 END


--script 2 to gather results from first stored procedure
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SM_COLLECTIONS_WTK_RANK'
DECLARE @Currency NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'GBP'
DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Billed'
DECLARE @ParameterValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1503515'
DECLARE @WhereField NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'FK_MATTER'
DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SPWithParams NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO ##holdingtable
FROM 
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=;UID=;PWD=','SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC 
dbo.CL_GetDynamicColumns2')

--set the parameters of the procedure
SET @SPWithParams = 'EXEC dbo.CL_GetDynamicColumns2' + @TableName + 
@Currency + @Type + @ParameterValue + @WhereField  + @ColumnList + 
@SqlCommand
--execute the procedure
EXEC ProcToTable 'holdingtable', @SPWithParams
--view the results
SELECT * FROM ##holdingtable
DROP TABLE ##holdingtable
```

Comment: What type are you expecting `@ColumnList` to be, and how do you expect it to be concatenated to the rest of your SQL string? It looks to me like you would need to iterate through the results of `SELECT L.TABLE_COLUMNS FROM @MyTableVar2 AS L` using a cursor and add each column to the dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: @cf_en No he doesnt. His columns are already concatenated in one string.

Comment: You write EXEC twice in your EXEC PRocToTable. You cannot do this. And for further debugging. Try to make PRINT statements to see where you code fails. This will make it easier for you to focus on your problem.

Comment: @plaidDK good shout, I didn't look closely enough at how the data is inserted.